# Meaning of ELF NT_FILE notes

Tags: linux, elf

E.g. in the ELF core dump we have things like these:

```
  Start         End Page Offset
0x08048000  0x08049000  0x00000000
    /hshare/prog
0x08049000  0x0804a000  0x00000000
    /hshare/prog
```

What is mapped exactly to what?

Answer (score 0):

> What is mapped exactly to what

You are effectively looking at the contents of `/proc/self/maps` for the binary at the time of crash.

In your case, `prog` is so small that its `.text` and `.data` fit on a single page. Thus `prog` is `mmap`ed twice: once with `r-x` permissions for `.text` (actually it's the first `PT_LOAD` segment, as `.text` has no meaning after linking), and once for `.data` and `.bss` (the second `PR_LOAD` segment) with `rw-` permissions.

Looking at the output from `readelf -Wl prog` may make it clearer.

If you make the `prog` larger (e.g. by using fully-static link with `-static`) and make it core dump, you'll see that the two mappings will now have different `Page Offset`.